# Hash decryption

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash

I have a hash decryption function. If input is `664804774844` output is `agdpeew`. I use modulo and division for finding letter index. But in while loop I written `i = 7` becauce I know output string (`agdpeew`) size. How I can find `i`?

A decryption function:

```
var f = function (h) {
  var letters, result, i;

  i = 7;
  result = "";
  letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";

  while (i) {
    Result += letters [parseInt (h % 37)];
    h = h / 37;
    i--;
  }

  return result.split("").reverse().join("");
};
```

An encrypted function:

```
hash (s) {
    h = 7;
    letters = "acdegilmnoprstuw";
    for(i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        h = (h * 37 + letters.indexOf(s[i]));
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: ''I have a hash decryption function'' actually you dont.

Comment: @leppie why I don't?

Comment: The property of hash functions is that they cannot be reversed. What language is this (add a tag)? What is `f` supposed to be? What exactly do you want to do and what problems do you have? Where is your hash "encryption" function? Please provide example inputs/outputs and *expected* values.Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I added encrypted code, and update my question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm looking for an algorithm, I will not specify the language

Comment: @ArtomB. Hashes can be reversed, it's just computationally expensive (more so depending on the has).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you handle overflows. If your "encryption" function allows inputs long enough that h would overflow at some point then you are stuffed and your current method of decryption wouldn't work at all.

If you can guarantee no overflowing then your final h will be the sum of terms of the form (An)x^n where An is the nth letter in your sequence converted to a number via your indexof method (and x in this case is 37)

Your decryption basically takes the x^0 term (by using mod x) and then converts that. It then divides by x (using integer maths presumably) to lose the old x^0 term and get a new one to interpret.

This means that you can actually just keep doing this until your `h` is 0 and at that point you know you've dealt with all the characters.

An interesting note is that x just needs to be greater than length of `letters` (because An must be less than x). A smaller X would give more possible input characters before overflow.

If you are allowing overflow then you have no way to do this unless you know how long the input was. Even then it might be tricky. If your input is unlimited in length then you could have a 1000 character input and with all those combinations there are a lot of possible values of h. Though in fact there are not. There are still 2^32 possible outcomes (in fact less with your algorithm) and if you have more than 2^32 possible inputs then you cannot possibly have a reversible function because you must have at least 2 inputs that would match that hash value.

This is why leppie says you cannot decrypt a hash value because you lose information in creating it that cannot be recovered. Unless you have constraints or some other information then you are stuck.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but if loop doing until he is 0 I have an unnecessary number `7` in last loop.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you started with a 7. Loop until 7 then.